# share settings between multiple machines by source control system

Tags: version-control, mercurial, sh

I have multiple linux machine.  I want to share my `.vimrc`, `.hgrc`.  But, there are a little difference between different machines.  Is there smart method?

I'm using mercurial.

```
mkdir settings
ln ~/.vimrc settings/vimrc
ln ~/.hgrc settings/hgrc
```

then use mercurial to keep settings.
There are a little difference of hgrc file on different machine.
I require to branch merge always.
I'm wonder is there better method?

Comment: [`rsync`](http://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) might work well for what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I typically do is have a .bashrc, etc. file that is common on all systems, and then I source a local version called `.bashrc.local` or something like that, that doesn't get saved in source control with the machine specific settings.

In .bashrc:

```
. ~/.bashrc.local
```

In .vimrc

```
:source ~/.vimrc.local
```

etc.

---

If you want to get fancy you can store your local settings files in source control by using your hostname as a discriminator on the local file name.  So instead of `.vimrc.local` you could do `.vimrc.machine1.local`, etc.

Comment: For hgrc the inclusion directive is `%include file`. See the [hgrc manual](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

There is another (overkill ?) technique that may complement other answers.

I use [puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) which is a tool for automatically configuring machines. I write my puppet config (stored in version control) then deploy it on the target machines. It offers a "template" feature which works for any file.

For example, you write a .vimrc.erb file like that :

```
ENV_VAR=<%= varvalue %>
```

with "varvalue" depending on the target machine. With correct puppet declarations (*"for machine xyz, put a .vimrc file in home generated from template .vimrc.erb with varvalue=xyz"*) you then deploy the config to the target machine.

It uses the powerful "embedded ruby" templating mechanism, so you can even write some ruby code to generate the values. You may want to use it directly without puppet : [erb](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)

Comment: @Daniel darn, page removed in the meantime ! I put a new one. Upvote if you're interested;)